# Find global index for first and last NA value by group

Tags: r, na

I have a data set of the form

```
#create data.frame
df <- data.frame(id    = rep(1:3,each=10),
                 value = rnorm(30))

#throw in some NAs
df[c(1:5, 25:30),2] <- NA 

df[1:10,]
   id      value
1   1         NA
2   1         NA
3   1         NA
4   1         NA
5   1         NA
6   1 -1.0763008
7   1 -0.4026228
8   1  1.6110506
9   1 -1.0626593
10  1 -0.4058101
```

I would like to find the first and last non-NA value by group. I tried to code up a function that does that and it works fine if there's  no grouping:

```
first.last.non.na = function(x){
  return(c(min(which(!is.na(x))),max(which(!is.na(x)))))
}
```

When I try to use this in combination with aggregate, it unfortunately only returns the indices of the first and last non-NA value *within* groups (as is to be expected):

```
aggregate(df[,2], by = list(df[,1]), FUN = first.last.non.na)
  Group.1 x.1 x.2
1       1   6  10
2       2   1  10
3       3   1   4
```

My desired output are the ''global'' indices of first and last non-NA values, i.e.

```
  Group.1 x.1 x.2
1       1   6  10
2       2   11 20
3       3   21 24
```

Any solutions that would also work with extremely large data sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea is to create a variable based on the row numbers before grouping. Using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 summarise(v1 = first(rn[!is.na(value)]), 
           v2 = last(rn[!is.na(value)]))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>      id    v1    v2
>   <int> <int> <int>
> 1     1     6    10
> 2     2    11    20
> 3     3    21    24
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Same idea as @Sotos in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[!is.na(value), .(x.1 = .I[1], x.2 = .I[.N]), by = id]

   id x.1 x.2
1:  1   6  10
2:  2  11  20
3:  3  21  24
```

Whereby we first filter for non-missing values of your `df` (in the `value` column) and then we extract the global row numbers (`.I`) for both first (`[1]`) and last (`[.N]`) value per each `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `aggregate`

```
res <- aggregate(value~id, df, function(x) range(which(!is.na(x))),na.action = NULL)
res$value[-1,1] <- res$value[-1,1] + cumsum(res$value[-nrow(res$value),2])
res$value[,2] <- cumsum(res$value[,2])
```

such that

```
> res
  id value.1 value.2
1  1       6      10
2  2      11      20
3  3      21      24
```